# Does dependency injection in Asp.Net Core MVC view impact performance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Im just wondering, if I use dependency injection in the mvc view, would that impact the performance of the website in any bad way, or is it bad practice?

Lets say i have IPost interface with some methods like GetAll().
The PostService class then inherits IPost and it's methods/properties.
I know I can then use that PostService in the view, but is that bad practice or does it impact the performance in any bad way?

```cs
@inject MyWebsite.Services.PostServices post
@if (post.GetAll().Any())
{
    // Some code here...
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it

Comment: This might be better asked on Code Review or Software Engineering SE sites.

Comment: it shouldn't impact performance so as you would notice, I use DI in an large MVC application and it performs the same. The benefit is you can now easily change the implementation class of IPost without touching the controller. You can also test the controller by injecting a Mock of IPost into it.

Comment: Oh ok, sound great. Thank you!

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 in its current form, this post would not be [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for CR because it lacks context. See ["Which Site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/341145) and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: Aren't you mixing concerns, though? The view should just be concerned with how to present the data. It should not know how to fetch the data.

Comment: @KennethK. Yes i understand that, just read a blog post about injecting the services to the view and using some of the methods there and thought if thats something you can do or should avoid.

Comment: Well, I'd say you avoid it unless you're doing view-specific things as described in  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @KennethK. Ok, thanks i will read that. I was reading the docs for dependency injection before but i was reading the fundamentals part. Thank you.

Comment: We don't usually think about the gazillion things that go into the processing of a single web request like matching the request to a route and a handler, deserializing request data, processing your view to create HTML, and more. The extra work that DI does is trivial. Yes, it does do some work, but so does everything else. So there's no need to worry about it.

Comment: Simply, yes. Does it matter? Likely, no. Like everything DI is a trade-off. You get better object lifetime management and less coupling, but the DI container will consume sort amount of resources and overall slightly affect perf. For 99.9999% of cases out there, the benefits of using DI clearly win over the negatives. However, if you need to be super highly optimized (which you likely don't) then it may be better to forgo it. The SO core, for example, doesn't use DI because it's only concern is pure bare-to-the-metal performance. They're also serving millions upon millions of requests.

Comment: Great answers, thanks i will read up on this and get a better understanding. This helped alot, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, DI brings overhead to your application like any other component do like the MVC framework or a ORM. How much depends on multiple things like DI framework, the injection type and the load of your platform. [Here you can find benchmarks of many DI frameworks](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison). On 500.000 injections you'll see a few seconds delay at worst.

### Realize what and why you optimize

Generally, you should know what you want to archive (e.g. page load time < 1 sek). Or what problem should be solved. For example, you should care differently on performance when developing for 100.000 userse a day, where this wouldn't be less important for only 500 users a day. This would be more focused on the backend, where you could save server costs when hosting a large application.

### Optimize your code

If you feel the need to optimize, first think about where it would be usefull to optimize. On DI you get a revenue by using it. You can consider this as best practice, since it prepares you application for automatic tests. So I would recomment checking first if you could optimize other parts of the application.

Your code already show a common pitfall:

```
@if (post.GetAll().Any())
{
    // Some code here...
}
```

It seems that `PostServices.GetAll` do something like:

```
dbContext.Posts.ToList();
```

which results in a `SELECT * FROM Posts` query. In other words: You fetch *all* data of the post table to detect if there is any inside. As this table grows, it would result in a massive overhead (imagine this part fetches 100, 1000, 10.000 or more datasets).

The database can do this much more effective! Simple use `dbContext.Posts.Any()` so that the db itself will check if there is any data, without returning a potentially large set of not required data.

This is just an example, there are much more ways to keep EF querys performant like using read only querys (which avoild the costs of EFs change tracker). You can find [some examples here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-tools/entity-framework-performance-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/), but feel free to search over SO or other sites about .NET Core/EF performance.

### Optimize your webapp

Don't just focus on backend speed! Todays webapps contain a bunch of css and also javascript. This can have a large impact on the *perceived load time* for your users. Your server can render the page in < 100ms. But when the browser need to load several MB of CSS with blocking JS, the visitor will feel your page slowly.

You should think about what's really neccessary, use bundles like gulp or webpack and optimize those files using minifying/uglyfing. It's also a good practice to load css in the head and js in the footer. This avoid blocking effects by js and your visitor will feel your page faster since css got loaded first ~> They see the page, where js can be downloaded and rendered a bit later.

### Choose components/librarys by performance

This already allows well performing applications in ASP.NET Core. But if this isn't enough for you, there are more ways to optimize. [Looking at benchmarks](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r17) you'll see that ASP.NET Core itself is a fast framework. Currently ranked on #6 with up to ~294.000 requests per second. Note that this is reached without any MVC or ORM technology. With EF you reach about 88.000 rps.

A realistic screw that can be tuned is your ORM. For example, see [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), a simple object mapper developed by the team behind stackoverflow. It's not a full ORM like EF that generates your SQL querys, but its core feature is to map a database result to a object of your entity. As you can see in the performance benchmarks, this is much faster than EntityFramework.

You need to decide for yourself, if this is worth for your application. It makes the app lighter, but you've to care about SQL queries. And it wouldn't be that simple to change to another database provider, for example. It depends on your requirements: A large site like SO can speed up things and save ressources, where smaller projects may not even really notice the difference.